# MySQL SUM Query not working when changin WHERE to = instead of >=

Tags: php, mysql

Why this query that sums different values from different tables works:

```
SELECT paymentMethodId, SUM(price) AS total FROM (
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM flights WHERE status >= 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM cruises WHERE status >= 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM cars WHERE status >= 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM hotels WHERE status >= 5 
 ) alias GROUP BY paymentMethodId
```

and this one (which only changes on the WHERE condition) doesnt:

```
SELECT paymentMethodId, SUM(price) AS total FROM (
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM flights WHERE status = 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM cruises WHERE status = 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM cars WHERE status = 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT paymentMethodId, price FROM hotels WHERE status = 5 
 ) alias GROUP BY paymentMethodId
```

I have to point that only on the cars table there're existing rows.

Comment: Does any row having `status = 5` exist?

Comment: @1000111 thx bro that was the problem, i didnt realize i updated all rows status and it ended up being none with status 5 hehe :)